# Создание таблицы c TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите как реализовать данную таблицу, каким инструментом воспользоваться лучше, а то на данный я на этипе TaybleLayout и TextBox?

А основной вопрос, как сделать, что бы все мои введенные данные при распечатке на этот лист, попадали в свои колонки. Идея в том, что бы я в программе заполнял пустые ячейки и при распечатке, печатало только в эти ячейки на нужном месте.

Может кто делал да есть гововый пример? или подскажите где почитать? 
А то как на консоль выводить это одно а на принтер не знаю с чего начать.
(Это нужно сделать на WinForms :( )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заполнение это одно, тут DataGridView вам в помощь, а формирование образа для печати - совсем другое и, вообще говоря, ни как не зависит от способа заполнения данных. Эти вопросы нужно разделить.

Comment: спасибо, DataGrid то что нужно

Comment: только вот не получается сделать как на фото "Количество" и "Отпущено", там одна ячейка поделена на две, не могу найти в свойствах DataGridView, как можно отформатировать к такому виду?

Comment: Для этого возможно потребуется сторонний грид

Comment: Как вариант, сделать хитрую шапку только в печатной форме, а для заполнения оставить отдельными колонками с более полным названием

Comment: Да я тоже об этом подумал, так наверное и сделаю